# How to navigate to a specific element's ID using Vue Router?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have this dataset :

```
data() : {

    navigation : {
        section : {
            story : {}
        }
    },
}
```

And I have three component, one for `navigation`, `section` and `story`.

My component works like this :

```
//navigation component

<div v-for="section in navigation.section" :key="section.id"> 
    <p> I am Section {{section.name}} </p>
    <section-component :currentSection="section"></section-component>
</div>
```

Inside my section component I have this.

```
//section component

<div v-for="story in currentSection.story" :key="story.id"> 
    <p> I am the Story about {{story.hero}} </p>    
    <story :content="story"></story>
</div>
```

And finally Inside my last component `story`

```
//story component

<div> 
    <p> Here is the story! {{content.story}}</p>    
</div>
```

Ok now what I want to do, I want to do a navigation who can go through my stories (like a chapter, or a book)

Example in my navigation component I have this :

```
 - Section batman
    - Batman story
    - Catwoman story
    - Bat story
    - Wheres robin
 - Animal Section
    - Leo story
    - Dog story
```

So I want, when I press on "Where's robin", my section component display the "Section Batman" and then scroll to "Where's robin".

I know you can use Vue.router to setup named route, so I tried this :

```
 {
    path: "/navigation/:sectionName/:StoryNameid",
    component: navigation,
    children: [
      { path: '', component: section }, children: [
      { path: '', component: story}]]
  }
```

I don't know where to give to Vue.router my 2 parameters and how to associate them with my section.

If possible, I would like to use a link like this.

```
www.mystorys.com/navigation/sectionBatman/wheresRobin
```

My display looks like this :

```
+------------------+               
| Section           |              
|  +--------------+ |                  
|  | Story1       | |              
|  +--------------+ |                   
|  +--------------+ |
|  | Story 2      | |
|  |              | |
|  +--------------+ | - 
|  +-------------+  |
|  | Story 3     |  |
|  |             | 
|  +-------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For displaying sections, you could use [Nested routes](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/nested-routes.html). Check out the linked docs, it specifies the exact use case that you want.
You need to place a `<router-view>` in your navigation component which vue-router will automatically replace with a `<section-component>`. Change your router paths definitions like so:

```js
{
    path: "/navigation/:sectionName",
    component: navigation,
    children: [
      { path: '', component: section },
    ],
  }
```

Add a router-view and pass the currentSection prop by section name:

```html
//navigation component

<div v-for="section in navigation.section" :key="section.id"> 
    <p> I am Section {{section.name}} </p>
</div>
<router-view :currentSection="getSectionByName($route.params.sectionName)"></router-view>

<script>
export default {
    methods: {
        getSectionByName(sectionName) {
            return this.navigation.section.find((section) => section.name === sectionName);
        },
    },
}
</script>
```

Next, for scrolling to your story, you could either

1. Give each story component an id and then add it to the route:

```html
<div v-for="story in currentSection.story" :key="story.id"> 
    <p> I am the Story about {{story.hero}} </p>    
    <story :id="story.id" :content="story"></story>
</div>
```

```html
<router-link to="navigation/sectionBatman#wheresRobin">Where's Robin</router-link>
```

2. Use vue-router's [scroll behaviour](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/scroll-behavior.html)

```js
const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [...],
  scrollBehavior (to, from, savedPosition) {
    return {
        selector: to.hash,
    };
  },
});
```

Comment: How can I give the :sectionName value ? I use a `v-for` for the list ? something like this `/edit/Batman ?

Comment: I've shown in the answer above, `$route.params.sectionName` will contain the `sectionName` you provide in your route. So with `/edit/:sectionName` route, if you browse to `/edit/Batman`, then `$route.params.sectionName` will be `'Batman'`

Comment: Thank you so much ! I had 2 path with 2 different ID so that's why I didn't understand why I had an "undefined". Great soluce I understand how it works now.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need nested routes

See here => https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/nested-routes.html

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/user/:id',
      component: User,
      children: [
        {
          // UserProfile will be rendered inside User's <router-view>
          // when /user/:id/profile is matched
          path: 'profile',
          component: UserProfile
        },
        {
          // UserPosts will be rendered inside User's <router-view>
          // when /user/:id/posts is matched
          path: 'posts',
          component: UserPosts
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
})
```